# Haskell readFile with text encoding as argument

Tags: haskell

I needed a version of `readFile` taking text encoding as its argument. I ended up with following:

```
readFile' e name = openFile name ReadMode >>= (flip hSetEncoding $ e) >&&> hGetContents

f >&&> g = \x -> f x >> g x
```

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. It seems like the thing I defined as `>&&>` should be something standard but I couldn't find it.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `liftM2 (>>)`, with `Control.Monad.Instances` imported.  There's no more succinct version of it in the standard libraries.

Comment: Or `liftA2 (>>)`.  I prefer the applicative instance for `(->) r`.  I don't know why.  :-P

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple "do block" approach reads nicely for this, not that it is any more succinct.

> readFile' e name = do {h <- openFile name ReadMode; hSetEncoding h e; hGetContents h}

Comment: Also useful: `writeFile' e f txt =  withFile f WriteMode (\ hdl -> hSetEncoding hdl e >> hPutStr hdl txt)`